# openGraph locale for Argentina

Tags: localization, facebook-opengraph

I was expecting [es_AR](http://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/es_AR/) but using es_AR for `og:locale` causes an error in the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="es_AR">
```

So which openGraph locale should I be using for Argentina? I only see these possible settings for español in the source...

```
'es_CO' => _('Spanish (Colombia)'),
'es_ES' => _('Spanish (Spain)'),
'es_LA' => _('Spanish'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'es_LA' looks like a general Spanish for Latin America, add that underneath the `es_AR line which is correct according to i18n standards, and the facebook debgugger should be.

The meta tags are also used on google+ and linkedin, and search engines like bing  so I would not removed `es_AR` when it is valid, but an extra tag could be aded for locale using `og:locale:alternate` for `es_LA` as described [here](http://ogp.me/).

Here is what facebook says, from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization

> The locales that Facebook supports are referenced in the Facebook Locales XML file. The codes in the XML file follow ISO language and country codes respectively, concatenated by an underscore. The basic format is ll_CC, where ll is a two-letter language code, and CC is a two-letter country code. For instance, en_US represents U.S. English.
>
> There are two exceptions that do not follow the ISO standard: ar_AR and es_LA. We use these to denote umbrella locales for Arabic and Spanish. For Spanish, we support a few specialized localizations.
>
> Your can determine the locale andlanguage of a person using your app through the locale field of the User Graph API object.

The [file](https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml) gives choices for Mexico, Columbia, Chile, Venezula, Spain plus the Spanish generic I mentioned which is `es_LA`.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me